# Finding highest value in a specific JSON field in bash

Tags: json, linux, bash

I am writing a bash script that curls POST an API. The response from the post has values returned in the following format:

```
{
  "other": "irrelevant-fields",
  "results": [
    {
      "datapoints": [
        {"timestamp": 1555977600, "value": 0},
        {"timestamp": 1555984800, "value": 15},
        {"timestamp": 1555992000, "value": 5}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to extract the highest figure from the "value" columns but I am having problems writing this code in bash. I am a beginner at JSON and there are no real references I can use to filter out the strings and values I don't need as each array is the same except for the timestamp, but I don't care about the timestamp, just the highest value returned.

My current code is just a generic way to extract the largest number from a file in bash:

```
grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+' | sort -n | tail -n 1
```

...but instead of `15`, that returns `1555992000`.

Comment: Is there a missing `[` at the beginning? What do you mean by "when references are the same"?

Comment: Why don't you use `grep value` to just get the lines with `value` on them before extracting the number and sorting?

Comment: Please show your code that returns the wrong answer. There's obviously a problem with the way you're filtering to just get the values, if you're also getting timestamps. But without seeing your code we can't tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: You should also look into using the `jq` utility for parsing JSON in shell scripts.

Comment: @Barmar Yep thats a great way to go around it. Its been a long day. I have added the full response now however I removed some references that are unique to my environment for security

Comment: Why you want return to be 20.0, while the highest value in your JSON is 46.0?

Comment: That JSON example was much larger than what a [mcve] would call for anyhow. I've cut it down to try to comply with the "minimal" part of that specification.

Comment: @MattB, ...we really don't want the "full" response; we want the shortest possible code and content *that can be tested to produce your exact error*. In addition to the previously linked MCVE page in Stack Overflow's help center, see the (closely related) SSCCE definition and "Tricks for Trimming" section at http://sscce.org/

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  Thank you for the edit, it is much better than I wrote. I appreciate the time you spent to get my question across better

Comment: @Dmitry 20 was in my original question before I edited it to include all of the JSON response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo '
{
  "other": "irrelevant-fields",
  "results": [
    {
      "datapoints": [
        {"timestamp": 1555977600, "value": 0},
        {"timestamp": 1555984800, "value": 15},
        {"timestamp": 1555992000, "value": 5}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
' | jq '.results[].datapoints | max_by(.value)'
```

The output will be like this:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1555984800,
  "value": 15
}
```

For more information, see this Medium post on [jq](https://medium.com/cameron-nokes/working-with-json-in-bash-using-jq-13d76d307c4), or the program's home page at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Might point out the ability to add `| .value` if the OP's desired output is really just the value (as they claim).

Comment: Ok I will paste the pipe here 
| jq 'max_by(.value)["value"]'

Answer (score 0):

Please process JSON with a proper JSON interpreter/parser, like [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html).

```
$ cat <<EOF | xidel -s - -e '$json/max((.//datapoints)()/value)'
{
  "other": "irrelevant-fields",
  "results": [
    {
      "datapoints": [
        {"timestamp": 1555977600, "value": 0},
        {"timestamp": 1555984800, "value": 15},
        {"timestamp": 1555992000, "value": 5}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
EOF
```

This returns `15`.

(or in full: `-e '$json/max((results)()/(datapoints)()/value)'`)